# Sum Squares by lists in Perl

Tags: perl, list

Code

```
sub sqrsumfunc {
    my $sum; $sum += ($_) * ($_) for @_; $sum;
}
```

which I tried to substitute by element-wise multiplication and its summing

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(sum);
my @x = @{ $_[0] };
my $Sxx = sum( @x * @x );
```

but there are much deviation from the actual result.

**How can you replace the first function with Perl standard functions?**

Comment: For the sake of all that is holy, please don't naively sum numbers if you are going to do Stats. See [Algorithms for calculating variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance), especially this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second chunk of code isn't written as a subroutine so there is no `@_` array to use and `my @x = @{ $_[0] }` won't work. It also differs from the first chunk because it is expecting a *reference* to an array of values, whereas the first subroutine just takes a list of values as parameters.

The main problem is that you are writing

```
my $Sxx = sum( @x * @x );
```

which squares the *size* of the array. What you need is

```
my $sum_xx = sum map $_ * $_, @x;
```

or, if you prefer

```
my $sum_xx = sum map { $_ * $_ } @x;
```

which is just different syntax for the same construct

Comment: Assume you would have a cross sum where you want to sum @x and @y where step is `$sum += $x[$i] * $y[$i]`. Which of these options is suitable for that? Something like `sum map $_[0] * $_[1], @x @y;` which however does not make sense to me.

Comment: I would probably write `sum map { $x[$_] * $y[$_] } 0 .. $#x`. Or `List::MoreUtils` has a `pairwise` function that let's you write `sum pairwise { $a * $b } @x, @y`